# Proper combination of NFL football scores won't print for odd numbers

Tags: java, addition

I created a program that takes a score from American Football and generates all possible ways to get that score in American Football. I just created a conversion-less touchdown method (that decrements the score value by 6) that combines a field goal method(decrements the value by 3) and a safety(decrements the value by 2). A problem is, when an even value is typed, there are no proper combinations that contains touchdowns, field goals, and safeties. The program works fine for odd values. I suspect an issue could be how *fieldgoalsnumbersprinted* returns its String value.

```
static int sixtouchdownnumbers(int c) //return type doesn't matter
{
    int touchdowns6 = c;
    int touch6counter = 0;
    int touch6divided = touchdowns6/6;
    int lesserdowns6 = touch6divided -1;
    String booth;
    String box;
    String scoreboard;
    String boothbox;
    String seat; 
    String boothboxseat;
    if(touchdowns6 < 6)
    {

    return touchdowns6; //this value doesn't matter. I just have this here so the method stops if the score is less than 6.
    }

    touchdowns6 = c;
    touch6counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= lesserdowns6; i++)
    {
        touchdowns6 = touchdowns6-6;
        touch6counter++;

        booth = "there were " + touch6counter + " touchdowns without conversion";
        box = Safetynumbersprinted(touchdowns6); 
        seat = Fieldgoalnumbersprinted(touchdowns6);
        boothbox = booth+box;
        boothboxseat = boothbox+seat;
        if(boothboxseat.contains("safeties")) //fixes an issue with field goal loop generating bad scores.
        System.out.println(boothboxseat);
    }

    return 0;
}
static String Fieldgoalnumbersprinted(int d) 
{
    int fieldgoals = d;
    int goalcounter = 0;
    int fielddivided = fieldgoals/3;
    int lessergoals = fielddivided -1;
    String scoreb;
    String oard;
    String scoreboard;
    String nosebleed = "Error"; //if this is printed, the for loop didn't assign the right value.
    if(fieldgoals < 3)
    {
    return "";  
    }

    fieldgoals = d;
    goalcounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= lessergoals; i++)
    {
        fieldgoals = fieldgoals-3;
        goalcounter++;

        scoreb = ", " + goalcounter + " field goals";
        oard = Safetynumbersprinted(fieldgoals);
        scoreboard = scoreb+oard;
        if(scoreboard.contains("safeties")) //fixes an issue with field goal loop generating bad scores.
        nosebleed = scoreboard; //potential cause of the problem.
    }

    return nosebleed; 
}

    static String Safetynumbersprinted(int a) 
{                                       
    int safeties = a;
    int safetycounter = 0;
    int safedivided;
    String scorehalf;

    if ( (a & 1) == 0 ) //only even scores can be reduced to zero.
    { 
        safedivided = a/2;
        for(int i = 0; i < safedivided; i++)
        {
        safeties = safeties-2;  
        safetycounter++;
        }
        scorehalf = " and " + safetycounter + " safeties: ";
        return scorehalf; 
        }
    else 

    { 
    return "";
        }   
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I just tried it with 44, and it did print combinations with touchdowns, safeties, and field goals.  It didn't print all possible combinations, though.  It's hard to figure out how your algorithm works; I see a couple methods, but I have no idea what their purpose is or what they're supposed to return.  Using "cute" names for variables that have nothing to do with the variables' purpose (`booth`, `box`, `nosebleed`) makes it even harder to figure out.

Comment: I don't know what output you're expecting and not getting.  My guess is that you haven't really planned out an algorithm that will give you the results you want.